# How to access second level in json object?

Tags: javascript

This is JSON object

```
{
 "key": "***************",
"****************": {
 "comment": "hello" 
}
"text": "world"
}
```

I want to return comment field, how?

Comment: item.key.comment

Comment: `comment` is not a property of `key`

Comment: You probably want to have a look at: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `item[item.key].comment` to access it

Edited based on [Stephen Ostermiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145388/stephen-ostermiller) comment.

Lets say you have a variable like this:

```
let item = {
  "key": "someDynamicString",
  "someDynamicString": {
    "comment": "hello" 
  }
  "text": "world"
}
```

You can access the value of **key** property by either

```
item.key
```

or

```
item["key"]
```

both of those will return the value of `item.key` which is `"someDynamicString"`

The latter option can be use to access object property which have dynamic key. Let say that "someDynamicString" key is not always "someDynamicString", but dynamically change based on `item.key`.

You can access that dynamic key with `item[item.key]` which is equal to `item["someDynamicString"]` and `item.someDynamicString`

so whatever the `item.key` value is, you can always access the second level in json object you asked about.

Furthermore, to access comment property inside the dynamic key: `item[item.key].comment`

Further explanation: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.